# django-ratings proving frustrating; need insight

Tags: django

I've been trying for two weeks to implement the highly regarded django-ratings with zero success.

I've followed all directions, which are not that detailed, and cannot figure out how to actually present a means for a user to submit a rating with the template.

There are no directions on how to load template tags associated with it, so it resulted in errors. After looking through the code, it appears "ratings" was the proper way to load the tags within the template, so I employed that.

I added 'djangoratings' to settings.py.

The following to my model:

```
    rating = RatingField(range=5)
```

I also did the following to urls.py:

```
from djangoratings.views import AddRatingFromModel

url(r'rate-my-post/(?P<object_id>\d*)/(?P<score>\d*)/', AddRatingFromModel(), {
    'app_label': 'report',
    'model': 'story',
    'field_name': 'rating',
}),
```

Added this to the template:

```
{% rating_by_user user on story.rating as vote %}
```

And nothing appears. No means for the user to vote. Nothing.

I cannot figure out what may be wrong here and after two weeks of tweaking and trying different methods, nothing works.

If anyone has an idea of what is required to present some interface for a user to vote using this app, I would be extremely grateful.

This link to the app is here https://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings#rating_by_user

Comment: what happened when you ran "python manage.py syncdb"?

Comment: It created the required tables. Using South and the migration worked. It's also listed in the dependencies. I just can't figure out how to present a way for users to actually vote using this.

Comment: @WhyNot I am getting same error.